# Linear mixed model with multiple dependent (correlated) outcomes

Tags: r, model, mixed

I would like to perform a linear mixed model with multiple dependent variables as these correlated (same outcome measured at multiple frequencies). As fixed factor I have gender and as random factor ear (as left and right ears are correlated)

```
Id  Gender      Ear     Frequency1  Frequency 2
1   Male        Right       23      95
1   Male        Left        87      60
2   Female      Right       83      98  
3   Male        Left        91      53      
4   Female      Right       78      94
4   Female      Left        99      87
```

I tried to perform a linear mixed model for the frequencies seperately

```
lme(frequency ~ ear*gender,  random = ~ 1|id,   data = data)
```

I would like to know whether gender and ear contribute to the model

Comment: What is the output of your model? The question might be better asked at  stats.stackexchange.com if it is rather about interpretation than programming... 
Did you transform your data into long format (one frequency column for both frequencies?)

Comment: which frequency column is used from the data frame?

Comment: Yes, the data is in long format. I wish to put both frequency columns as dependent variable. Thank you for the advice. I will ask the question on stats.statistics!